# Webpack running without errors but browser empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, web, webpack

I am trying to build a web application using React, Typescript and webpack. 
This is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
      entry: './src/app.tsx',
      // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
      devtool: "source-map",

      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
      },

      resolve: {
        // Add ".ts" and ".tsx" as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "ts-loader"
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ]
          },

          // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
          {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
          }
        ]
      },

      devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
      }
    };
```

My tsconfig.json file :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
    } ,
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Demo Project
  </title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/styles.scss';

interface HelloProps {
    compiler: string;
    framework: string;
  }

const Hello = (props: HelloProps) => (
    <h1>
      Hello from {props.compiler} and {props.framework}!
    </h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Andrew Mead",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run dev-server` and open the browser, I get a blank screen with the Elements showing this:

[image]

What am I missing? Please help! 
This is my first time building an app using Typescript and webpack I am pretty lost.

Comment: `../dist/main.js` is probably wrong. Do you mean `/dist/main.js`?

Comment: @UjinT34 When I Ctrl+click, it takes me to the file. Doesnt that mean the path is correct?

Comment: Your editor and `devServer` might use different root paths